# add_action('init') in WordPress functions.php extension seems to be breaking Jetpack activation?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, jetpack

I've been having issues with this plugin another developer made to inject code into the function.php file in WordPress without manipulating the one in the theme. I added the `if (!is_admin()) {` line which solved a few issues with dashboard controls but now when I try to connect to wordpress.com to activate Jetpack its bringing me to the front page of my site with this error message written in the body of my site :

Not found, error 404
The page you are looking for no longer exists. Perhaps you can return back to the site's homepage and see if you can find what you are looking for. Or, you can try finding it by using the search form below.

If I deactivate this plugin they made Jetpack activation will work, but I want to know what is causing the problem. Pretty sure it has to do with the `add_action('init', 'check_user_logged_in');` part of the code but I don't know what to replace it with. I've tried replacing init with wp_head but it breaks styling in another plugin on my page. Any ideas? Here is the code below.

```
<?php

/* Your code goes below here. */

ob_start();

function check_user_logged_in(){
  if (!is_admin()) {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { ?>
      <style  type="text/css" media="screen">
      #theme-my-login-2 .widget-wrap .widget-title { display: block !important; }
      </style>
   <?php
    } else { ?>
      <style type="text/css" media="screen">
         table.sidebar_result{margin-top:-10px;}
      </style>
<?php 
    }
  }
}

add_action('init', 'check_user_logged_in');

/* Add Read More Link to Excerpts */
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'get_read_more_link');
add_filter( 'the_content_more_link', 'get_read_more_link' );

function get_read_more_link() {
    return '...&nbsp;<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">[Read&nbsp;More]</a>';
}

/* Your code goes above here. */
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `check_user_logged_in()` is written with a lot of stupidity in mind as it will definitly destroy any WordPress website as the CSS snippets are printed to the screen in the WordPress `init` phase (one of the earliest loading phases).

This will destroy any redirects from the `template_redirect` hook and also destroy the view. I would probably not trust the authors of such a Plugin.

However your approach of adding this with `wp_head` action was quite right (you also could use `wp_footer` action). Still it is a bad approach since styles should be enqueued with `wp_register_style()` and `wp_enqueue_style()`.

If the CSS code is destroying your theme you either just remove the add_action line or you alter the CSS to fit your needs.